# How to populate another column with a sequence value generated for an identity column?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sequence

I have a table that has a column that is determined by a sequence using the identity column thing, so after a record is inserted (or during, I'm not sure how it works behind the scenes, only that it does) it gets a number one higher than the previous record.

I'm writing a program where there is a condition that leads to a record having that number also be in another column. Is there a way to do this without just making the record and then modifying it immediately afterwards?

Thanks!

Edit: My code:

```
String insertion = "INSERT INTO DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN "
                    + "(SOURCE_ID, ROOT_ID, SOURCE_TABLE, CONFIDENCE_IS_SAME,"
                    + " IS_ROOT_PHYS, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, POSTAL_CODE) VALUES "
                    + "(" + p.getPhysicianID() + ", " + Integer.toString(root_id) + ", STI.PHYSICIAN, 1, 0, " + p.getFirstName()
                    + ", " + p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getPostalCode() + ");";
```

and the table:

```
CREATE TABLE UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN 
(
  SOURCE_ID NUMBER 
, ROOT_ID NUMBER 
, SOURCE_TABLE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, CONFIDENCE_IS_SAME FLOAT(126) 
, IS_ROOT_PHYS CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, UNIQUE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, POSTAL_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    UNIQUE_ID 
  )
  USING INDEX 
  (
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN_PK ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN (UNIQUE_ID ASC) 
      LOGGING 
      TABLESPACE DATAL03 
      PCTFREE 10 
      INITRANS 2 
      STORAGE 
      ( 
        INITIAL 65536 
        MINEXTENTS 1 
        MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
      ) 
      NOPARALLEL 
  )
  ENABLE 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE DATAL03 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL;
```

In this instance, I want to set ROOT_ID to be equal to the UNIQUE_ID assigned to that record.

Comment: Show us the code you have!

Comment: So, you want `ROOT_ID` to initially be equal to `UNIQUE_ID`. Can it change later (to a different value)?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it can change later or not. In the present implementation it doesn't matter but it might matter later.

The reason I'm doing this is because this insert is only running in certain conditions, where I want ROOT_ID and UNIQUE_ID to be equal. There are conditions where that's not the case.

Comment: So, you want some inserts to do this (root same as unique) but some other inserts to not do it?

Comment: This insert that I am writing right there. I don't want it to be a script or trigger or something associated with the table, I want to do it exclusively in that insertion statement at the top.

Edit: actually, whenever IS_ROOT_PHYS is 1, root should be set to unique. I suppose that could be a trigger?

Comment: Yes, it could if this condition is absolutely and always specifying whether this is going to happen or not.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a condition that specifies 1005 whether `root_id` has to get the same value as `unique_id`, you could use a `TRIGGER`. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER root_unique_trg
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.is_root_phys = 1)
BEGIN
    :NEW.root_id := :NEW.unique_id ;
END ;
```

Tested in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b452a/1)

Comment: Did you try it? I haven't tested and I fear it may not work as it is.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I'm getting syntax problems.

I managed to get it to work, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was testing in SQLfiddle. Edited with a working version.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to produce a working trigger based on ypercube's help.

```
create or replace TRIGGER ROOT_PHYSICIAN_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF  INSERTING AND :NEW.is_root_phys = 1
THEN :NEW.root_id := :NEW.unique_id;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: The `referencing old as old new as new` line is pointless.  And there is no need to have the `inserting` check in the `if` statement in a `before insert` trigger.  More of a concern, though, assuming the `unique_id` is being assigned in a trigger, which seems like the only way your `insert` would work, is that Oracle is free to execute your triggers in any order but this code will fail if the trigger that assigns `unique_id` hasn't fired yet.  Almost certainly, you'd want to add this logic to the existing trigger rather than creating a new trigger.  Or set up a trigger order explicitly.